# How does clustering of ejabberd nodes work?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Does it work like master-slave way, where xmpp clients connect to a master node, and master node uses the slave nodes to distribute the load?

If not, how load balancing can be done after clustering of ejabberd nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes are equal and there is no master. State is kept in mnesia or mysql (like roster table, session etc.). Configuration is replicated over all nodes.

Usually it means there is LB in front of the whole cluster. One cluster is represented by one domain. You can have more and federate them.